# Can You Open Chometz Cabinets?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven

Is there any experience about the contracts used to  lease the specific rooms of a house or furniture with chometz that would indicate whether it would be allowed to enter if one found  another food item or needed to check something there?

Comment: How is anyone but your authorized agent supposed to know whether you sold the cabinet or not? I don't see how anyone here can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Double AA. Talking about a case where you did sell your cabinet.

Comment: So you are asking if you can open someone else's cabinet without asking? What does that have to do with Chametz? Sounds more like a "stealing" kind of question.

Comment: @DoubleAA, actually, it seems more like a breaking-and-entering/trespassing question. I don't see anything about stealing. I voted to close as Psak. Maybe I should have voted to close as unclear?

Comment: Or VTC as CYLA (consult your local attorney).

Comment: @SethJ Trespassing is a form of stealing, seemingly

Comment: I have edited the question in order to try to address the issue that prompted the close vote. But I may be biased because I also offered an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I asked the question of my Rav, he answered that part of the agreement with the non-Jew was that I could have access to the areas rented out to the non-Jew on Pesach. The access should be for as short a time as possible.

[Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/h/pes/l/48966396.html) poses the question:

> 15. During Pesach, may items be taken from sections of the house that have been sold?

and answers:

> The contract gives permission to the seller to retrieve an item from
>   these locations in times of need. However, one should not do so too
>   often, since this would indicate that the sale has not been taken
>   seriously.

It is possible that a specific contract will not allow for the seller to retrieve an item from a location in time of need. Therefore, it is necessary to check the contract first.

Comment: Thanks, Avrohom Yitzchok! I just spoke with my Rav, and he also said it's fine. I think the general da'as, and this is what I was wondering, is you're providing a lease to the storage area with rights reserved, i.e., you can access briefly if necessary. (As was correctly pointed out, though, you should really ask your own Rav, if possible, if the need arises.)

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer that if you find Chametz in your house, it can be put into the closet that had been **rented** (not sold) to the non-Jew for his chametz because the chametz belongs to him and should be put there. This was part of a discussion about destroying Chametz that had been found during Pesach (especially on Shabbat or Yom Tov).

[what should be done to chametz on a shabbat day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70324/what-should-be-done-to-chametz-on-a-shabbat-day/70326#70326)